# LinkedIn Authentication not working on Fragment in android

Tags: java, android, authentication, linkedin-api

I am creating an app that has the LinkedIn login. I am following [this](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth) documentation. But when I click on the login button, the app redirected to the LinkedIn app and asking for login. When successful login it redirected to my app. But nothing happens. Nothing happens on `onActivityResult` also. 
Below is my code .**Login implemented on fragment**

```
 LISessionManager.getInstance(getActivity()).init(getActivity(), buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthSuccess() {
                getLinkedInProfile();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "success" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, true);
```

//

```
private static Scope buildScope() {
    return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
}
```

and onActivityResult as follows:

```
     @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        LISessionManager.getInstance(getActivity()).onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Already added hash and package name on LinkedIn developer console. Did I am missing anything? Please help

Comment: Same thing here also. I am getting the same code worked in activity. But when used in fragment it is no working!!!

Comment: Actually I found a solution for @Pratheesh

Comment: Then please write it as an answer. Will be useful for many others like me. @Vinayak B

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is found that the `onActivityResult` for LinkedIn sdk triggres on the parent activity rather than fragment `onActivityResult`. So you have to write following code into your parent Activity's `onActivityResult` for triggering fragment's `onActivityResult`.

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    yourFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Log to ensure whether function is called.